# Mybatis always log "Property 'configLocation' not specified"

Tags: mybatis

I test Mapper with JUnit, and I get the log info bellow infinite loop.

14:07:54.040 [main] DEBUG o.m.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Property 'configLocation' not specified, using default MyBatis Configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for others to help you, please show your application context setup for org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean. This is a working example:

```
<bean id="YOUR_BEAN_ID" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="YOUR_DATA_SOURCE"/>
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:*Mapper.xml"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:TO_YOUR_MYBATIS_CONFIG.XML"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just a information that you haven't included `<property name="configLocation" value="path_to_mybatis_config_file.xml"/>`.

Note that this message is not indicating any error, as it's not always neccessary to include this XML file, because some configuration can be performed directly using bean `property` tags.

Comment: Right, you don't necessarily need a MyBatis configuration since MyBatis Spring can find / load mapper XML files via other configuration. The config XML is only useful if you are changing general properties.

Comment: Can it slow down the starting process if one don't specify `mapperLocations`